# LINQ Error with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get this LINQ to work but fails with the error.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

Basically I have `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and I'm trying to group the data, as in:

```
string sql = @"SELECT [t0].[Contact_Account] AS [Contact], [t0].[Work_Phone] AS [WorkPhone], [t0].[SR_NUM] AS [SRNum] ";
sql += "FROM [Base_SR] AS [t0] ";
sql += "WHERE ([t0].[Country] = 'USA') AND (NOT ([t0].[Work_Phone] LIKE '+%')) ";
sql += "AND ([t0].[Product] = 'SP3D') AND (DATEPART(Year, [t0].[DateOpened]) = {0})";

sql = String.Format(sql, curYear);

var sqlCmd  = new SqlCommand(sql, new SqlConnection(connectionString));
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
var dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
var siebelRows = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

return siebelRows.GroupBy(sr => new { AreaCode = sr.Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 3), 
          Contact = sr.Field<string>("Contact") },
     (key, lst) => new Customer 
     {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      AreaCode = key.AreaCode,
      CustAccount = key.Contact,
      FirstPhoneNo = lst.First().Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 10),
      FirstSRNum= lst.First().Field<string>("SRNum"),
      SRCount = lst.Count()
     })
     .Take(5);
```

Any thoughts ?

DigEmAll's suggestion helped (thanks) and I had to do this:

```
public class GroupKey
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

And then change the LINQ to this `GroupBy` key:

`GroupBy<DataRow, GroupKey, IEnumerable<Customer>>`

```
return siebelRows.GroupBy<DataRow, GroupKey, IEnumerable<Customer>>(sr => new GroupKey
{
    Contact = sr.Field<string>("Contact"),
    AreaCode = sr.Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 3)
},
    (key, lst) => new Customer
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            AreaCode = key.AreaCode,
            CustAccount = key.Contact,
            FirstPhoneNo = lst.First().Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 10),
            FirstSRNum = lst.First().Field<string>("SRNum"),
            SRCount = lst.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(c => c.SRCount)
        .Take(5);
```

Don't like creating a concrete type for the key...any way around this?

Comment: Seems like LINQ is looking for the 2nd overload that requires an IEqualityComparer public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>> GroupBy<T, K>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  Func<T, K> keySelector,
  IEqualityComparer<K> comparer);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `Field<T>` in your Anonymous type definition.

You should specify the type `T` (cannot be inferred from the usage), then compiler will recognize the correct `GroupBy` overload.

---

**EDIT according to OP changes:**

You don't need to create a concrete type, just specify explicitly the right `T` in `Field<T>(...)`, so in your code:

```
sr => new { AreaCode = sr.Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 3), 
            Contact = sr.Field<string>("Contact") }
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

OK, I've edited your question because actually your `<...>` were hidden (don't use `<code><pre>` manually, just click on the appropriate button ;-) ).

Anyway, your last code has an error in the `GroupBy` types specification:

is not `<DataRow, GroupKey, IEnumerable<Customer>>`,

but `<DataRow, GroupKey, Customer>`

because you just have to specify the inner Type of the returned `IEnumerable`.

Then, I've tried your last code, and also removing the concrete type `GroupKey` (and obviously removing the GroupBy types specification) it is perfectly valid:

```
var customers = siebelRows.GroupBy( 
    sr => new 
    {
        Contact = sr.Field<string>("Contact"),
        AreaCode = sr.Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 3)
    },
    (key, lst) => new Customer
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        AreaCode = key.AreaCode,
        CustAccount = key.Contact,
        FirstPhoneNo = lst.First().Field<string>("WorkPhone").Substring(0, 10),
        FirstSRNum = lst.First().Field<string>("SRNum"),
        SRCount = lst.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.SRCount)
    .Take(5);
return customers;
```

Comment: Good point, I missed that... But in that case the compiler is not showing the actual cause of the error

Comment: I think StackOverflow stripped the '<' out since it's there already. So that makes it puzzling...looks like the issue is with the incorrect signature I was using. It should be this one public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
 Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector
)

Comment: Since I'm returning IEnumerable<Customer> from the actual method.

Comment: Thanks..I changed it so that I get the latest SR->DateOpened .Select (x =>new {Contact=x.Contact_Account, SiteId=x.SiteID, DateOpened=x.DateOpened,
          WorkPhone=x.Work_Phone, SRNum=x.SR_NUM} )
     .AsEnumerable()     
     .GroupBy (sr => sr.SiteId, 
        (siteid,lst)=> new {SiteId=siteid, SRCount= lst.Count(), 
           SR = lst.First (l =>l.DateOpened == lst.Max (l => l.DateOpened))}) but now it again complains of IEqualityComparer ??

Comment: Mmh, maybe the problem is that you're using `l` (lowercase L) for 2 nested lambda expression :   `[...]First(l =>l.DateOpened == lst.Max (l => l.DateOpened))`. Try to change the second with another variable name. Anyway, this GroupBy overload seems very sensible, and it gives wrong compiler error informations.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You mixed your GroupBy and Select.</strike> Try the following as a work-around (looking into the overload you're using):

```
return siebelRows.GroupBy(sr => new
                          { 
                              AreaCode = sr.Field("AreaCode")
                                           .Substring(0, 3),
                              Contact = sr.Field("Contact")
                          })
                 .Select(kvp => new Customer
                                {
                                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                    AreaCode = kvp.Key.AreaCode,
                                    CustAccount = kvp.Key.Contact,
                                    // rest of the assignment
                                }
                 .Take(5);
```

Comment: Your solution should return the expected result, but actually I think the OP is trying to use [this GroupBy overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx), so he's not really "mixing" anything... I can't see why the original code doesn't compile

Comment: I'm using the overload for GroupBy public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, E>> GroupBy<T, K, E>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  Func<T, K> keySelector,
  Func<T, E> elementSelector);

Comment: Thomas beat me to the explanation (:

Comment: @Sunit, in that case your code doesn't match the method signature... the only one that seems to match is the one I linked to.